# C# - Input to process buffer

Tags: c#, input, process, buffer, streamwriter

I have an .exe file of a very simple C program (only I/Os are `printf`/`scanf`s). (In the final project, the C code can be **any** C code, so the amount/order/types of inputs are not set).

Now I want to execute it through a C# code, with predefined inputs for the `scanf`s.
I used this code (based on the example from MSDN):

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "File.exe";
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

myProcess.Start();

StreamWriter myStreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput;

myStreamWriter.WriteLine("3");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("3");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("1");

myStreamWriter.Dispose();

myProcess.WaitForExit();
myProcess.Dispose();
```

(I also tried writing one string with newlines - didn't work)

The problem is that the process simply ignores inputs that are written to it when it is not expecting them (before reaching the next scanf).
Though, if there is some delay between the `WriteLine`s, it does seem to work properly.

So my question is - is there any kind of alternative that fills the process's input **buffer** instead of giving it input when it is expecting it?
Or simply, any that will make the process receive all of the inputs, without any delay set in between writing them (preferably from a single string, e.g. `"3\n3\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n1\n"`)?

P.S. `StreamWriter` doesn't seem to work when the process is expecting a keyboard input (e.g. `getch`). Is there any method that will support keyboard inputs too?
For example, if I have two `scanf`s and a `getch` between them, I want this string to be translated into the inputs: `"1\n a 2\n"` (spaces not necessary)

EDIT: I **can** manipulate the C code though, so I can turn the `getch`s to `getchar`s, etc.

Comment: What does this have to do with C?

Comment: Oh you're right, it doesn't...
It's just that the Process is a C program

Comment: If the program uses the non-standard getch() then you are pretty screwed.  Hacking SendInput() is very little fun.

Comment: Haha ok, so a solution for the standard inputs will suffice

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.